# JOOQ - Why does my DAO store empty datasets?

Tags: dao, jooq

i hope anybody can help me. First of all, I'm a newby in using JOOQ. I've created some Java-Classes wie the codegen tool.

I can load existing Records from database already, e.g.

```
AddressDao dao = new AddressDao(context.configuration());
Address address = dao.findById(1);
```

But when i change some values and calling update, the record in database stays unchanged.

```
address.setName("Test");
dao.update(address);
```

When i'm creating a new Record, a new record in database will be created, but it is empty.

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setName("test");
dao.insert(address);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` for your address table? Also, what do you see in the `DEBUG` log output? See this sections on how to turn it on: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging/

Comment: 17:43:02,776 DEBUG [org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl                 ] - Query is not executable  : update `test`.`address`
set
  [ no fields are updated ]
where `test`.`address`.`ADR_id` is null
17:43:02,776 DEBUG [org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl                 ] - Query is not executable  : update `test`.`address`
set
  [ no fields are updated ]
where `test`.`address`.`ADR_id` is null
------------
I'm wondering, why ADR_id is null, because in address-object id has a value

Comment: You must be doing something that you haven't mentioned in your question (e.g. a `RecordUnmapper` configuration that is wrong). I can't see, for example, why the ID would be `null` in your POJO. Can you debug-step through jOOQ code to find the reason, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've experimented with a DefaultGeneratorStrategy. When i remove this strategy, datasets will be stored correctly. So anything has to be wrong with my strategy.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, if you implement your own custom [`GeneratorStrategy`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/) you will still need to make sure to adhere to the rules specified by the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) for the `DefaultRecordMapper` to work.

The `DefaultRecordMapper` is reflection based, so it tries to match source record field names with target POJO attribute names by certain conventions. If you, for example, prefix all your attributes with FOO, then jOOQ can't simply match a `COLUMN` to a `fooColumn` attribute!

You can override the default with a [`DefaultRecordMapperProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/), but that's a lot of work for something that would otherwise work out of the box.

Now, in the special case of generated `DAO` types, arguably, this is a bug, because the `DAO::mapper` method has been added specifically to override the default behaviour. Perhaps, generated `DAO` should implement a custom `RecordMapper` that is capable of mapping between records and your custom named POJOs. I've created an issue for this:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15374

Irrespective of this `DAO` related bug, just be aware that in general, the `DefaultRecordMapper` is unaware of your `GeneratorStrategy`